# How to specify the headings for the fields which is specified in the awk statement?

Tags: linux, awk

Below code is my **awk statement**...I need to specify `the headings for the each fields` like name,age and phone_number in my output...How to give headings in the awk statement...How can i do that..

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print $1, $2, $9 }' > "abc.txt"
```

Desired output:

```
 name              age          phone_number
  rat               26             5662200
  cat               25             562212
```

Comment: Ya ; } its a typo error...Forget about wc -l ...I need to add new headings to the above specified fields in the awk script...How can i do that

Answer (score 2):

In your inital question you asked about how you can add column headers. The answer to this is using the `BEGIN` condition:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN { print "name", "age", "phone_number"} { print $1, $2, $9 }' > "abc.txt"
```

In your edit you asked about how you can visually align your columns. This possible by using `column -t`:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN { print "name", "age", "phone_number"} { print $1, $2, $9 }'|column -t > "abc.txt"
```

Comment: Am getting the output like how i mentioned in my question ...Header is not aligned with the column..What should i do

Comment: See my edit please.

Comment: How can i make heading as center align...see my edit pls

Comment: You might like `printf "%10s\t%10s...", $1, $2, ...` if you can predict the maximum widths.

Comment: @ Jeff..Can u be pls be more clear

Comment: @disha please edit your question again. Show us some lines of your input and the desired output. And take care of the correct formating!

Comment: sir...I need to add the column heading in my awk statement...and the heading should be centered...like how i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

```
I have done this by below awk and sed command

awk 'OFS="\t"{print $1,$2,$9}' filename | sed '1i name\t age\t phonenumber\t'
```

Comment: Sir..Pls see my edits..I gave the above commands...am getting error like "Sed" : No such file or directory

Comment: Before sed command you have used "<" kindly replace it with pipeline "|"

Comment: Its not working sir

Comment: @disha Your error is `Sed no such file or dir.` it is `sed` not `Sed`.

Comment: It is not working